# During booting the following is coming "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" in LINUX latest Ubuntu version

Tags: xubuntu

During booting the following is coming
"No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" in LINUX latest Ubuntu version

Comment: A few BIOS need a boot flag on a primary partition even though grub does not use a boot flag. Also do you have a boot loader in MBR or is system new and using UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your HardDisk is not recognized.  Boot from the Ubuntu LIVE CD and check for your hard disk, whether it is recognized.

Regards
PK

Comment: thank you :-D
What do you mean exactly "recognized"?
The BIOS reports my disk, as well as the installation process which shows the same label as the BIOS when prompted to choose the installation's location.
And the partitions were created, filled with ext4 and OS and software?!
I acknowledge that this Acer is out-of-age and that the 21.04 is young, so all hardware could not be completely taken into account (and it appears to work with 20.04), but what I think is a boot loader issue (BIOS vs UEFI, the latter being mostly today) could be at least warned, aiming not writing in vain the entire OS